# Need index for Each Loop with Array

Tags: vba, excel

I have an array which I populate with Varibles from an excel table. I then use an each loop to cycle through this array.
The allocation of the array lines up with some cell I would like to populate.

```
'arRow is a Dynamic Array, that varies in size
For each vIndex in arRow
 if vIndex = 0 then
     'do nothing
   else
    'Populate corisponding cell
     Cells(2, ???).value = vIndex
  end if
next vindex
```

How would I find the index for the Each-Loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this two ways. Both methods require a "counter" of sorts, as the array doesn't have any sort of indexed property you can access.

With a counter:

```
Dim i as Long
i = 0
For each vIndex in arRow
 i = i + 1
 if vIndex = 0 then
     'do nothing
   else
    'Populate corisponding cell
     Cells(2, i).value = vIndex
  end if
next vindex
```

Or with an indexed loop over the array (assumes a 1-dimensional array, but could be modified for multi-dimensional if needed):

```
Dim i
For i = LBound(arRow) to UBound(arRow)

   ...

Next
```

Comment: I think the Lbound to Ubound is the more elegant of the two, and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This fills `B1:B3`

```
arRow = Array(11, 22, 33)

For vIndex = 0 To UBound(arRow)
    Cells(vIndex + 1, 2).Value = arRow(vIndex)
Next
```